# Link between convergence in distribution and almost sure convergence

Tags: convergence

Let $X_n$, $Y_n$ and $Y$ be random vectors. If $X_n \xrightarrow[]{d} X$ and $X_n - Y_n \xrightarrow[]{a.s.} 0$. Can we prove that $Y_n \xrightarrow[]{d} X$ ?

Comment: In Van der Vaart, A. W. (2000). Asymptotic statistics (Vol. 3). Cambridge university press, theorem 2.7 (iv) page10 the same result is established but with convergence in probability instead of almost sure convergence.

Comment: Doesn't almost sure convergence imply convergence in probability?

Comment: This is Slutsky's theorem and as whuber told, $\rm a. s. $ convergence implies $\overset{\mathrm P}{\to}.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can.

First, define $Z_n := X_n-Y_n$

Now,
\begin{align} 
Z_n \overset{a.s}{\to} 0   & \implies Z_n \overset{p}{\to} 0 \quad \text{(van der Vaart, Thm. 2.7. (i))} \\
& \iff \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}(|Z_n-0|>\epsilon)=0, \forall \epsilon>0 \quad \text{(definition of $\overset{p}{\to}$)} \\
& \iff \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}(|(-Z_n)-0|>\epsilon)=0, \forall \epsilon>0 \quad \text{(as $|Z_n-0|=|Z_n|=|-Z_n|=|(-Z_n)-0|$)} \\
& \iff (-Z_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0
\end{align}

where the reference is: Vaart, A. (1998). Asymptotic Statistics (Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Further, we have $Y_n = X_n - (X_n-Y_n) = X_n - Z_n = X_n + (-Z_n)$

So, as $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and $(-Z_n) \overset{p}{\to} 0 $, we have by Slutsky's Lemma (van der Vaart Lemma 2.8 (i)) that
$Y_n = X_n + (-Z_n) \overset{d}{\to} X + 0 = X$ i.e. $Y_n \overset{d}{\to} X$